# Unable to deploy to SAP Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry

Getting error -- when run from CLI -- cf push

yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `https:/...` into []string

my manifest.yml file

```
applications:
- name: test
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  path: ./web
  buildpacks: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  services:
    - node-uaa
```

Answer (score 3):

The `buildpacks` entry in `manifest.yml` expects an array of strings. The error message is saying that it can't unmarshall the provided string value to the expected array of strings type.

Either change the entry to the singular:

```
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
```

or wrap the value in an array:

```
  buildpacks: [ https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack ]
```