# yaml: unmarshal errors: cannot unmarshal !!str `https:/...` into []string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am having an error when I try pushing my app to cloud foundry. The manifest.yml file is the right format and also referenced it with that given as an example on the ibm forum but I get this error which doesn't add up in my opinion. What am I doing wrong here? Anybody to help out please?

Error

yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `https:/...` into []string

[image: error seen]

Comment: Add details like the manifest file, relevant source code, the command you used to push and the full error message, not just a section. Add it as text, not as picture. And remove any confidential stuff.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the yaml file. But the issue i have resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got an answer for this from someone else [Unable to deploy to SAP Cloud foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595879/unable-to-deploy-to-sap-cloud-foundry)

My error was because I was writing buildpacks and giving it a value of a string url instead of an array. Once I enclosed it inside an array, it worked fine. This is because IBM cloudfoundry recently changed from using buildpack to buildpacks which meant using an array instead of a single url string.